# Theme in MergedDictionary in Silverlight not working design time

Tags: silverlight, resources, themes

Ok, this is driving me crazy now. I have a Silverlight 5 project. Not long ago we decided to theme our project, just to make it pop more. I found a theming implementation and went ahead.

First i used the .Theming namespace from the Silverlight Toolkit. I used the explicitly build theme.dll's. There was a shortcoming with this though, that i didnt have the ability to customize the theme. So i decided to just use the theme.xaml instead, and implement it by using `<MergedDictionaries>`.

The problem with this approach though, is that i lost the ability to see the theme in design time. In runtime it works fine. But that's just not good enough, when i wan't to customize the theme.

I implemented the theme by using merged dictionaries in App.Xaml like so

```
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/eCP;component/Themes/WhistlerBlue.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
```

If i put the same  blok in my MainPage, the theme instantly turns on in design time there. But it shouldnt be necessary to do it on every Silverlight page?

So in short: If i implement the theme in with MergedDictionaries in App.xaml it does not work in design time. If i do it on a specific page, it does work.

Funny thing though, if i open my project in Expression Blend, it works fine in design time.

My first notion is, that something is messing with my visual studio 2010 SP1. Maybe something in a hidden project file or something, but i don't know.

Anyone able to help?